# Derivative of stochastic integral "$\int_0^t \exp(X_s)\sin(s+2t) dW_s$"?

Tags: stochastic-analysis

If $W$ be the Wiener process and $X_t$ be an stochastic process,how can compute the derivative of stochastic integral,
$V(t)=\int_0^t \exp(X_s)\sin(s+2t) dW_s$,

$dV/dt=?$

Comment: The stochastic integral is not differentiable.

Comment: Is it possible to express $$W_s=f(X_s)$$? If so, you can derive or use the [Discrete Derivative](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Discrete_derivative).